# how can i run some custom commands in a loop sequentially

Tags: bash, shell

There are variables that I need to change and run sequentially within certain codes.For example, the ionex_list variable looks like this and i need to change this in a loop. I have 3 variable files like this and 9 pieces of data in a row (ionex_list,receiver_ids,data_record).

```
ionex_list             data_record
jplg0910.19i.Z         ISTA00TUR_R_20190910000_01D_30S_MO.crx.gz 
jplg0920.19i.Z         ISTA00TUR_R_20190920000_01D_30S_MO.crx.gz
...                    ...
jplg0980.19i.Z         ISTA00TUR_R_20190980000_01D_30S_MO.crx.gz
jplg0990.19i.Z         ISTA00TUR_R_20190990000_01D_30S_MO.crx.gz
```

For example, I need to show ISTA00TUR_R_20190910000_01D_30S_MO.crx.gz as -dataFile in rnxEditGde.py, but I get the error "File: "/y2019/d091" does not exist" and I cannot show the path. these .gz files are a few directories under from the directory I'm working in. Since I couldn't pass the rnxEditGde.py part, I can't see if the codes below work properly.

```
dir=`pwd`
function pl {                
  sed -n "$1p" $2
}

for j in {091..099}; do
ids=$(pl $j receiver_ids)
ionex=$(pl $j ionex_list)
dataRecordFile=$(pl $j data_record)

gd2e.py -mkTreeS Trees
sed -i "s/jplg.*/**$ionex**/g" $dir/Trees/ppp_0.tree
rnxEditGde.py -dataFile "/y2019/d${j}/**$dataRecordFile**" -o dataRecordFile.Orig.gz

gd2e.py \
      -treeSequenceDir Trees \
      -drEditedFile** $dataRecordFile** \
      -antexFile goa-var/etc/antennaCalsGNSS/igs14_2038.atx  \
      -GNSS https://sideshow.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/JPL_GNSS_Products/MultiGNSS_Rapid_Test\
      -runType PPP \
      -recList **$ids** \
      -staDb /goa-var/sta_info/sta_db_qlflinn  \
      >gd2e.log 2>gd2e.err 
done
```

Comment: A code segment should contain only your literal, exact code. Don't try to add formatting like `**` -- anything there we should be able to assume is _exactly your code and nothing else_.

Comment: Also, http://shellcheck.net/ will point out a bunch of quoting-related issues; you might want to start there.

Comment: (and as an aside, see https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete re: function declaration syntax; the `function` keyword is a holdout from 1980s ksh, while the modern, POSIX-standardized syntax is `pl() { ...; }`)

Comment: Getting back to practical matters -- one way to build a better question is to use xtrace, as in, `bash -x yourscript`, to observe execution and compare between actual and expected behavior; that'll help you write a narrow, specific question focusing on where those things diverge (particularly if you compare the `set -x` trace from a command run by the script from a trace of the hand-written, working version of that same command).

Comment: ...and btw, as a rule, using the `pl` command here is very expensive. It'd be better to read all three files in parallel a line at a time than to read each one from the very start every iteration.

Comment: ...as an example of that: `while IFS= read -r id <&3 && IFS= read -r ionex <&4 && IFS= read -r dataRecord <&5; do ...; done 3< <(awk 'NR >= 100 { exit } NR > 91 { print }' receiver_ids) 4< <(awk 'NR >= 100 { exit } NR > 91 { print }' ionex_list) 5< <(awk 'NR >= 100 { exit } NR > 91 { print }' data_record)` -- there we use awk to get only the relevant range, but we run it _once total_ vs running sed once _per line_ as your current code does.

Comment: This might not be an issue, but in your line    >> sed -n "$1p" $2 <<,  did you intend to put  "$1", and NOT  "$1p"  ???   Also, until you've sorted out the issue, you might want to remove the "-n" from that "sed", in order to get positive feedback that all is well.  Also, using "-i" for  "sed" is not advisable until you know that the function being performed is actually what you want done.  Best to program defensively, even when some functions allow you to behave otherwise.